# Populating dictionary with same keyname in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have an XML with a bunch of key-value pairs, that have same key names. I want to save them as a JASON to PGSQL DB. As far as I can see, I can store this pairs in Python dictionary variable while I'm going through XML and collecting the whole list. The problem is that I'm not able to add them to dictionary as they have same key names and override previous element. For example, I have a dictionary of that structure:

```
data=[{'contactid': 'id0', 'score': 'score0'},{'contactid': 'id1', 'score': 'score1'}]
```

How I can add another record with following structure:

```
{'contactid': 'id2', 'score': 'score2'}
```

How I can access them? Delete?

Comment: `data.append()` ?

Comment: I don't get your point. It's a list, so why couldn't you append a new dictionary to `data` ?

Comment: I'm kind of new to Python. data.append() is doing exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a new dictionary to your list just use the method : `append()`.

If you want to access a given dictionary of your list, whether you know its position and you just do `list[index]` where `index` is the position of your dictionary in the list, or you can do as follows to look for it using its values :

```
request_list = [] # list that will contain dictionaries you are looking for

# Say you are looking for dictionary with values : id0 and score0
mask = [(data[i]['contactid']=='id0') & (data[i]['score']=='score0') for i in range(len(data))]

for i, bool in enumerate(mask):
    if bool:
        request_list.append(data[i])
```